# Android: Cannot access other app's SharedPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I've been searching for days to solve this, but with no success.

I want to get the shared preference settings from my old app and put it on to my new app.
but I've encounter some security issue (suspect).

my code:

```
Context c = createPackageContext("my.app.pkg", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);            
SharedPreferences sp = c.getSharedPreferences("my.app.pkg", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
```

Running the code above giving me this:

> Attempt to read preferences file /data/data/my.app.pkg/shared_prefs/my.app.pkg_preferences.xml without permission

even thought the object sp is not null, but it does not retrieve anything from my old app.

I tried googling around and seems like most people can run the code above with no errors.
Is there anything I've missed out?

Comment: that's flat out wrong, see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've done exactly this for our Android book [Android in Practice](http://www.manning.com/collins/). The key is to use the same process and user ID for both apps. The sample code and sample apps are on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/android-in-practice/source/browse/#svn/trunk/ch08) (SharedProcessApp1 and SharedProcessApp2). You can go from there.

Comment: This is one possible solution. but it requires to upgrade both my old app and new app in order to make it works. That's too many steps for an upgrade. But a good way for future use. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but that's the only possible way. As was mentioned before, Android apps are sandboxed and are assigned unique Linux user IDs. Unless they share the same ID, you won't be able to do what you're trying to achieve, not on a non-rooted device at least.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed share preferences across applications. That's why it's called SharedPreferences.

What you need to do is make sure both application are signed with the same certificate and they both share the same SharedUserId in the AndroidManifest.xml file: [read here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid).

This is because the SharedPreferences you get from

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
```

has always MODE_PRIVATE.

However in an application you can also get a SharedPreferences object within a Context with the following:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("my_public_shared_prefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

which you can freely retreive from another app with the following:

```
Context context = createPackageContext("my_target_app_package", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);            
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("my_public_shared_prefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

Make sure you don't store any private information there because it's WORLD readable, which means you and anyone else can read that data.

To finish, if you want to retrieve the SharedPreferences of your old app you will need to update the old application with a SharedUserId in the Manifest file.

Comment: Thanks for the details! I just tried your solution by adding shared user id to both manifest, it does not work right away, I have to uninstall the current old app and install the one with shared user id. if not doing this way, it can't even have permission to read it own shared_pref folder.

Comment: No of course not. That's how Linux file permissions work. A file created by one user belongs to that user. Unless you chmod or chown it, the only option is to remove and recreate it (that's what the reinstall of the app does)

Comment: One thing: the answer posted here does not exactly do what you want, since it will share the preferences with EVERYONE. Security nightmare? You only want to share to apps you control, so I strongly suggest to use the approach I use in the AIP sample app.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I've never tried to update an existing application with the SharedUserId but what you say makes sense, now I understand it better. I'll look at matthias solution as well.

Comment: Beware! "update the old application with a SharedUserId in the Manifest file" will *break* you app. Doing that will result in your app being unable to read its own data

Answer (score -1):

Android APplications runs in their own sandbox, so one application can not access data of other activity. BUt If an application want to share some of its data, this can be achieved by ContentProvider.

See Content Provider: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html